# Plot in for loop

Tags: matlab, neural-network, perceptron

I have implemented the single layer perceptron using the following code:

```
%%
clear all;close all;clc
%%
uni1 = 0.5 + rand(250,2);
uni2 = 1.5 + rand(250,2);
n = size(uni1,1);
m = size(uni2,2);
uni1 = [uni1 -1*(ones(n,1))];
uni2 = [uni2 ones(n,1)];
data = [uni1;uni2];
a=randsample(1:2*n,2*n);
data=data(a,:);
b = 1;
w = [0.5;0.5;0.5];
x = [ones(2*n,1) data(:,1:2)];
d = data(:,3);
y = zeros(2*n,1);
alpha = 0.01;
%%
idx1 = data(:,3)==-1;
data(idx1,3)=0;
idx = logical(data(:,3));
figure;
scatter(data(idx,1),data(idx,2),'bo')
hold on
scatter(data(~idx,1),data(~idx,2),'rx')
%%
itr = 300;
for j=1:itr
    for i=1:2*n
        aa = w'*(x(i,:))';
        y(i) = sign(w'*(x(i,:))');
        if y(i) ~= d(i)
             w = w + alpha*(x(i,:)' * d(i));     
        end
        Xax = 0.5:0.5:3; Yax=-(b*w(1)+Xax*w(2))/w(3);
        plot(Xax,Yax,'k--')
    end
end
```

I would like to draw the line in the training process to see how it is being adjusted. I put the plot function in the for loop but it only plots the final line. How can I accomplish my goal?

Thank you

Comment: Add `pause(.5)` or `drawnow` after the `plot` statement?

Comment: It prints lots of black dotted lines for me.

Comment: Thank you so much, `pause` is what I was looking for to create the "Animation"

Comment: drawnow should be better for you as pause will pause exactly for 0.5 while drawnow will only pause until necessary to draw.

Comment: Yes, I had to adjust the pause time, but drawnow is perfect too, thanks